# how to create test into with django

Tags: django, testing, integration-testing, django-testing, django-tests

I just started to create an app and now I m trying to do somme test on it so I write a test code however it always return a 200 code even when I put a wrong URL that doesn't exist

here is the code

```
class TestViews(TestCase):
c=None
response = None
def setUp(self):
    User = apps.get_model('auth','user')
    User.objects.create_superuser("admin", "Admin", "Admin")
    self.c = Client()
    self.response = self.c.post('/login/', {'username': 'admin', 'password':'admin'})


def testAudit(self):
    
    self.response.get('/actors/audit')
    self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code,200)
   
def testGetFile(self):
    
    self.response.get('/actors/GetFile',{'file_name' : 'file1'})
    self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code,200)
   
    
def testDetail(self):
    
    self.response.get('/ffff')
    self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code,200)
```

can anyone help or does anyone went throught this problem
tnx

Comment: What's in the page for `/ffff`? And what are you urls? If you test beyond the response code, you should soon start seeing a better test suite.

Comment: it is a page thatdoesn't exist however while execution the test detail methode i have a 200 code the tes is OK

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the status code for the
`self.response = self.c.post('/login/', {'username': 'admin', 'password':'admin'})` in all the 3 tests, may be if your code was:

```
response2=self.response.get('/ffff/')
self.assertEquals(response2.status_code,200)
```

it would have failed